# Is there a replacement for xobni on outlook mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there an equivalent for xobni on mac and MS outlook ?

they say they dont support outlook on mac http://www.xobni.com/support/?view=18

but i was wondering if there was any other tools people used that was similare

Thanks

Comment: Can you please briefly describe what it does, and maybe add its main feature to the title too?

Comment: Xobni is a plug-in to search email, contacts and attachments, and does things like threaded views, grouping emails from the same people. And I don't think there's remotely anything the same, considering how new Outlook 2011 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in email stats (like xobni has as well) then checkout Mailsum for Mac.

Link = [Mailsum](http://www.mailsum.com)

It has something funny as well, you can compare performance with your friends or co-workers :=)